# How do I update my location on my developer story/CV?

Tags: support, developer-story

I've updated the location in my general profile, but my developer story and CV still show the old location.

I was a subscriber on the orginal careers site if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the *Developer Story* tab.

Go to *Developer Story* > *Edit*, and fill in *"Where you live"*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, i was apparently not recognizing the Edit was available with a hover.